# Row-wise sum for columns with certain names

Tags: r, sum

I have a sample data:

```
SampleID  a      b     d     f       ca      k     l    cb
1         0.1    2     1     2       7       1     4    3
2         0.2    3     2     3       4       2     5    5
3         0.5    4     3     6       1       3     9    2
```

I need to find row-wise sum of columns which have something common in names, e.g. row-wise `sum(a, ca)` or row-wise `sum(b,cb)`. The problem is that i have large data.frame and ideally i would be able to write what is common in column header, so that code would pick only those columns to sum

Thank you beforehand for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select the columns that have 'a' with `grep`, subset the columns and do `rowSums` and the same with 'b' columns.

```
 rowSums(df1[grep('a', names(df1)[-1])+1])
 rowSums(df1[grep('b', names(df1)[-1])+1])
```

Comment: Could it be modified so that it returns matrix, data.frame and position of columns is  not `+1` all the time. So, could be the code a bit more general.

Comment: I clicked! Thank you! But i don't have much reputation yet, it to be appeared. But i really did!

Comment: Thank you. But could you please explain me a bit more.How can i modify your code to sum rows of columns which are for example 7 columns away from each other?

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  The `grep` gives the column index of the columns that have the same pattern in the column name.  I added `1` to the grep output because I was `grep`ping on the subset of dataset that doesn't include the first column.  So, if I understand your comment, it should work.

Comment: Sorry, i modified sample data frame. How in this case would `a` and `ca` be summed? Thank you!

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  It should be the same i.e. `rowSums(df2[grep('a', names(df2)[-1])+1])#
[1] 7.1 4.2 1.5`  You can check the subsetted columns `df2[grep('a', names(df2)[-1])+1]`

Comment: Sorry,,but in real data it does not work. Actual columns with similar names  are 6th and 13th for example. But your code sum something else now..

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  Perhaps in your real data, the patterns are different.  The regex pattern works for the names you showed in the example.

Comment: Could you suggest something if column names look like this `XXL:VLDL.CE` and `XL.VLDL.CE`. Those for example i need to sum

Comment: If `VLDL.CE` is the common element, then `rowSums(df2[grep("VLDL\\.CE$", names(df2))])` should work

Comment: and what if only CE is common, could i use `CE$` :) ?

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  Yes, you are right, `grep("CE$",..`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: A little question to clarify...sorry for disturbing. what if in my `DF` i have more than 2 columns with same part of the name. Does it sum all of those columns?

Comment: @OlgaAnufrieva  The `grep` will get all the columns that match the pattern.  So, it can be 3, 4 or any number

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output as a data frame, try using dplyr

```
# Recreating your sample data
df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1, 2, 3),
             a = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5),
             b = c(2, 3, 4),
             d = c(1, 2, 3),
             f = c(2, 3, 6),
             ca = c(7, 4, 1),
             k = c(1, 2, 3),
             l = c(4, 5, 9),
             cb = c(3, 5, 2))
```

Process the data

```
# load dplyr
library(dplyr)

# Sum across columns 'a' and 'ca' (sum(a, ca))
df2 <- df %>%
    select(contains('a'), -SampleID) %>% # 'select' function to choose the columns you want 
    mutate(row_sum = rowSums(.)) # 'mutate' function to create a new column 'row_sum' with the sum of the selected columns. You can drop the selected columns by using 'transmute' instead.

df2 # have a look

    a ca row_sum
1 0.1  7     7.1
2 0.2  4     4.2
3 0.5  1     1.5
```