# Summing rows with a dynamic column range specified by another value in that row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowsum

I am working with a set of binary data for months of the year similar to the sample tibble below but with tens of thousands of rows. I am trying to add a column to the existing table that sums each row between the month specified by the column `Month` and the final month `Dec`. For example, I would sum columns `Nov:Dec` = 0 for the first row, `May:Dec` = 8 for the second, `Jan:Dec` = 11 for the last, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Jan,~Feb,~Mar,~Apr,~May,~Jun,~Jul,~Aug,~Sep,~Oct,~Nov,~Dec,~Month,~Expected,
  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Nov",0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"May",8,
  0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"Aug",5,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"Jan",9,
  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"Dec",1,
  0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"May",7,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,"Jun",6,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,"Jul",5,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,"Feb",4,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,"Oct",3,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,"Mar",2,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,"Jan",11,
)
```

I tried using the `mutate()` and `sum()` functions in a row-wise manner with a dynamic column range based on the value of Month at each respective row `n()`. However, only the first row value of Month (Nov) gets used--so, instead of creating a new column with the "Expected" sums shown in df, I get the sum of the column range `Nov:Dec` for each row.

```
test <- df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    Actual = sum(c_across(df$Month[n()]:Dec))
  )

> test
# A tibble: 12 × 15
# Rowwise: 
     Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec Month Expected Actual
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 Nov          0      0
 2     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May          8      2
 3     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Aug          5      2
 4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jan          9      2
 5     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Dec          1      2
 6     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May          7      2
 7     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jun          6      2
 8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1 Jul          5      2
 9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1 Feb          4      2
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1 Oct          3      2
11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1 Mar          2      2
12     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0 Jan         11      1
```

I've reviewed other posts with a similar albeit not the same aim ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343806/sum-rows-by-selected-columns-specified-by-a-character-string-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544366/rowsum-with-dynamic-column-range), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693876/row-wise-sum-for-columns-with-certain-names?rq=3)), but I am still struggling to find a solution. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: For the first post, this is very well written and also an interesting question.

Comment: Thank you both! This answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `Month` to a ordered factor, and row-sum those columns whose names are greater than or equal to `Month`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Month = ordered(Month, levels = month.abb),
         Result = rowSums(across(Jan:Dec, ~ ifelse(cur_column() >= Month, .x, 0))))

# # A tibble: 12 × 15
#      Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec Month Expected Result
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <ord>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 Nov          0      0
#  2     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May          8      8
#  3     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Aug          5      5
#  4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jan          9      9
#  5     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Dec          1      1
#  6     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May          7      7
#  7     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jun          6      6
#  8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1 Jul          5      5
#  9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1 Feb          4      4
# 10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1 Oct          3      3
# 11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1 Mar          2      2
# 12     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0 Jan         11     11
```

**Note:** You must use `ordered()` instead of `factor()` here because `>=` is not meaningful for ordinary factors.

---

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `purrr::map` and `pick` for variable selection

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Exp = purrr::map_dbl(Month, ~ sum(pick(.x:Dec)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 15
     Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec Month
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 Nov  
 2     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May  
 3     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Aug  
 4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jan  
 5     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 Dec  
 6     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 May  
 7     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1 Jun  
 8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1 Jul  
 9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1 Feb  
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1 Oct  
11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1 Mar  
12     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0 Jan  
   Expected   Exp
      <dbl> <dbl>
 1        0     0
 2        8     8
 3        5     5
 4        9     9
 5        1     1
 6        7     7
 7        6     6
 8        5     5
 9        4     4
10        3     3
11        2     2
12       11    11
```

Comment: This is a good idea!(+1) But I think it's not feasible in practice because `rowwise` + `map` is time-consuming if the dataset is slightly larger.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I agree, it’s definitely slower than approaches without rowwise, but might still be fast enough in practice. For me it served as a kind of proof of principle, if it’s possible to get to a solution without using too much workarounds, just working with the given variables.